# Silverman AEC: Lemma IV.6.3 [on the convergence of formal logarithm]

Tags: elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory, formal-power-series, formal-groups

In Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Lemma IV.6.3(a) states that

> Let $R$ be a ring of characteristic $0$, complete with respect to a discrete valuation $v$, and let $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a prime with $v(p)>0.$
> (a) Let $f$ be a power series of the form $f(T) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n} T^n$ with $a_n\in R$.
> If $x\in R$ satisfies $v(x)>0$, then the series $f(x)$ converges in $R$.

The proof is given as follows:

> ${\it{Proof.}}$
> For a general term of $f(x)$ we have
> $$
> v(a_nx^n/n) \geq v(a_n) + nv(x) - v(n) \geq nv(x) - v(n) \geq nv(x) - (\log_p n)v(p).
> $$
> This last expression goes to $\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.
> Since $v$ is nonarchimedean and $R$ is complete, the series $f(x)$ converges.

**My question** about this proof is that nowhere does it show that $v(a_nx^n/n)\geq 0$ for all $n$ -- I think this is needed for us to know that $f(x)$ converges in $R$ (instead of just converging in the fraction field of $R$.)
Later (Theorem IV.6.4(b), where $f$ is the formal logarithm), under the assumption that $v$ is normalized (that is, $v(\mathrm{Frac}(R)^\times) = \mathbb{Z}$), Silverman thinks that it is obvious that if $v(x)\geq r$, then $v(f(x))\geq r$. But I do not find it obvious.
Could anyone please explain why the convergence is in $R$?
Thanks in advance!

**Thoughts.** Using the lower bound obtained in the proof given above, to show that $v(a_nx^n/n)>0$ it suffices to show that $\displaystyle v(x) > \frac{\log_p n}{n} v(p)$ for all $n\geq 1$.
We clearly have that $p=\mathrm{char}(R/\mathfrak{m})$, where $\mathfrak{m}=\{x\in R| v(x)>0\}$. If one can show that $\color{red}{\textrm{$v(p)=\min\{v(x)|x\in \mathfrak{m}\}$}}$, then we are done since $\displaystyle \max_n \frac{\log_p n}{n} \leq \frac{1}{e \log p} \leq \frac{1}{e \log 2} < 1$ and thus $\displaystyle v(x) \color{red}{\geq} v(p) > \frac{\log_p n}{n} v(p).$
As for Theorem IV.6.4(b), if $v$ is normalized and my thoughts above are correct, then $\color{red}{v(p)=1}$ and $$ v(a_n x^n / n) \geq nv(x)-(\log_p n) v(p)) \geq v(x) - \frac{\log_p n}{n} v(p) > r-1,$$ from which it will follow that $v(a_n x^n / n) \geq r$ for all $n$.

**Update:** Thanks to @Torsten Schoeneberg and his comment, this is a slight mistake of the book.

Comment: I think that's just a slight mistake, and in general $f(x)$ won't be in $R$ but in its fraction field. Just take as $R$ the ring of integers in $\mathbb Q_p(p^{1/r})$ and let $a_i = 0$ except $a_{p^k} =1$, then $v(f(x))= (\frac{k}{r}-k)\cdot v(p)$ which can be made arbitrarily small (certainly negative) by choosing $r \gg k \gg 0$. Likewise for the logarithm series, no other source I see claims that the image stays inside the valuation ring everywhere it converges. It's only guaranteed to do so for $\lvert x \rvert < p^{1/(p-1)}$ which just in case $R=\mathbb Z_p$ coincides with its domain.

Comment: An expansionlet or commenticle on @TorstenSchoeneberg ’s comment above: The logarithm in question will be convergent on $\{z\in\Bbb C_p:v(z)>0\}$. The set of values (the “range”) will be all of $\Bbb C_p$, as you can see by trying to solve, when $w\in\Bbb C_p$ is given, the equation $w=\log(z)$ for $z$. (You see this by drawing the Newton Polygon of the logarithm.)